# How to execute useEffect only once inside looped component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have component where I have array of data that is being looped using map and rendered a new component base one that and inside the looped component I have a useEffect that fetches the data from the api but it runs same api twice.

Here is the code

I am looping through array of rule_set_versions which is in this case size of 2

```
const ExpandedContent = ({ experiment }) => {
  return experiment.rule_set_versions &&
    experiment.rule_set_versions.map((ruleSetVersion) => <RuleSetVersionCollapse key={ruleSetVersion.id} ruleSetVersion={ruleSetVersion} />)
}

const ExperimentsCollapse = ({ experiment }) => {

  return <React.Fragment>
    <div className={styles.experiment_collapse_root}>
      <Collapse>
        <Collapse.Panel className={styles.experiment_item} extra={<ExtraTest experiment={experiment} />}>
          <ExpandedContent experiment={experiment} />
        </Collapse.Panel>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

Here is my RuleSetVersionCollapse snippet

```
const ruleSet = useSelector(state => state.ruleSet)

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!ruleSet.id) {
      dispatch(getRuleSetAction(ruleSetVersion.rule_set_id))
    }
  }, [dispatch])
```

And the useEffect runs twice even though the **ruleSetVersion.rule_set_id** is same on both the case.

Can anyone suggest any way I can solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Does it still run twice if you omit `dispatch` from the dependencies?

Comment: Yes i added ruleSet.id there but still the same

Comment: If you have an empty array for dependencies, your effect will run only once. If it runs twice, it means you have 2 components.

Comment: Yes the array that is iterating the map has size of 2

Comment: Ah I see. Effects are local to component instances. They don't interact with each other.

Comment: Any idea how can I restrict to running it only once if the id is same?

Comment: You could track if it ran or not in a higher piece of state that you pass down as a prop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230476/discussion-between-sahil-paudel-and-slava-knyazev).